# Can we drop local indexes in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

Can you please let me know can we drop local indexes in Oracle?

I have created 6 local indexes & 1 global index  for my table.

Thanks,
Sreenivas

Comment: Well, why do you think you cant?

Comment: So,we can drop local indexes  & global indexes as normal indexes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `drop index`:

```
create table tab1(
  id number
)
partition by hash(id)
partitions 8
;

create index loc_tab1_id_idx on tab1(id) local

select count(*) cnt
  from user_indexes
 where lower(index_name) = 'loc_tab1_id_idx'

CNT
---
1

drop index loc_tab1_id_idx ;

select count(*) cnt
  from user_indexes
 where lower(index_name) = 'loc_tab1_id_idx'

CNT
---
0
```